# Is it possible to have music accompany the BURG screen on startup?

Tags: boot, screen, music, burg

I'm brand new to Ubuntu, but I managed to get 12.04 LTS up and running on my Dell Inspiron 15r. Afterwards, I wanted a snazzier boot screen, so I installed BURG and chose my themes and whatnot. Now I want to know if it's possible to have some music accompany BURG screen right after my laptop posts, like, an .mp3 file playing at the same time I'm choosing my operating system.

Comment: [Like this?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49c-_YOkmMU&feature=youtube_gdata_player)

Answer (score 1):

The grub menu will be displayed only after the music stops playing.

This command can be used to set a tune (in this example Super Mario) as your music with the grub menu:

```
echo "GRUB_INIT_TUNE=\"1000 334 1 334 1 0 1 334 1 0 1 261 1 334 1 0 1 392 2 0 4 196 2\"" | sudo tee -a /etc/default/grub > /dev/null && sudo update-grub.
```

- Super Mario Tune via [CommandLineFU](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8275/grub2-set-super-mario-as-startup-tune).
- [GRUB Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html)